# retrieve two user records, from their username, only if they have a common record in a another table

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to figure out how to do a query to retrieve two user records, from their username, only if they have a "double profile" together.

My tables look like:

```
doubles =>
  id
  user_1
  user_2
  profile_text

users =>
  id
  username
  url_username
  birthdate
  and so on
```

Say i have this record in doubles table:

```
id    user_1    user_2         profile_text
5       14        16      Welcome to our profile
```

Say i have these 2 records in users table (among with many others):

```
id   username   url_username   birthdate
14    John         john        1990-05-09
16     Bob          bob        1991-07-04
```

When a user goes to www.mysite.com/double/john/bob i want to retrieve the 2 users, but only if they have a record in the doubles table  (not caring whether their id's are in user_1 or user_2).
The url_username is what is typed in the url (the reason for this column is that i have danish letters that are replaced for the url), and i retrieve this from the url.

Is this even possible?

Edit:
If changing the table structure would be able to make it more efficient, i am good with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't build out your tables to test it but I think this query should work:

`select * from users, doubles where (doubles.user_1 = users.id or doubles.user_2 = users.id) and users.url_username = 'THEUSERNAME';`

I used url_username in my where clause, assuming you already have a way of parsing out the url.  I would say it was better to use one of the actual user id's though.

Ok, here's a query using joins that I think accomplishes what you want.  (Joins are faster than subqueries, and preferred if possible.)

As for how fast this is, you'd have to test it out, and it would obviously depend on how many records you're looking at.  Note that this query is not doing anything to protect you from sql injection.  (I'm just using what you have in the url, but you would need to make sure it was safe before passing it to the database.)

`select 
  d.* 
from 
  users u1, 
  doubles d, 
  users u2 
where 
  (
    (d.user_1 = u1.id and d.user_2 = u2.id)
   or
    (d.user_1 = u2.id and d.user_2 = u1.id)
  )
and 
  (u1.url_username = 'john' and u2.url_username='bob');`

I've made an sql fiddle here if you want to play with it, or check that my database is correct.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5acc/12

Comment: That does not work. It needs to retrive 2 users (from their username), but only if both their id's are in a record in the doubles table.

Comment: Ok, do you know both the user id's?  (As in, can you use them in your query based on the url? )

Comment: Nope, i dont know the id's unfortunately. So i might have to make a subquery for the id, but i'm a little worried about performance. i could also store the url_username value in user_1 and user_2 instead. That would make the query easy. But my main concern is performance. What do you think?

Comment: Ok, I'm testing this out.  I'll post back shortly.

Comment: Hmm, I just realized, you want a result of both rows from the users table, my above query will return the single row from the doubles table.  I'll have to come up with a new query.

Comment: Well it's actually fine that it is one row, that just makes it easier. This is exactly what i needed, and it looks very clean. Thankyou for all the time you've put in it, i really appreciate it!